# ReactJS Material UI autocomplete: How to Configure data source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using [material ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete) autocomplete in one of a react components. The data source is received from the server (response to a asynchronous call)  and has the following shape

```
const dataSource = [{
 id: 001
 firstName: 'fname',
 lastName: 'lName
}]
```

And Configuration is as following

```
const dataSourceConfig = {
 text: 'fName',
 value: 'id'
}
```

What i want to do is to concatenate `firstName` and `lastName` and provide it to `dataSourceConfig`

```
const dataSourceConfig = {
 text: 'fName' + 'lName',
 value: 'id'
}
```

But this does not work. Could someone please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i think it will work-

```
const dataSource = [{ 
      id: 001,
      firstName: 'fname', 
      lastName: 'lName'
}]
```

Create a newDataSource with one extra key "fullName":

```
const newDataSource = dataSource.map(item => {
        return Object.assign({fullName:item.firstName+ " " +item.lastName},item)});
```

Assign this key in dataSourceConfig:

```
const dataSourceConfig = { 
     text: 'fullName', 
     value: 'id'
}
```

Use this newDataSource in place of dataSource in autocomplete.